# Begining Assembly- assembly function called from C gives "object not a function" error

Tags: c, assembly

I'm trying to compile my first assembly code and am having issues calling my assembly function from my main C program. I am on Ubuntu 12.04 using Eclipse 3.7.2 with the GCC compiler. This code is copied pretty much verbatim from lecture, and I'm just trying to get it to run to be able to step through it and watch the assembly instructions. But for some reason it gives the following error:

```
../src/addus.c: In function ‘main’:
../src/addus.c:21:13: error: called object ‘addus’ is not a function
make: *** [src/addus.o] Error 1
```

Main C file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int addusina (int, int);
int addusinc (int, int);

int
main (void)
{
  int a, b, sum;
  a = 5;
  b = 6;

  sum = addusina (a, b);
  printf ("You added %d and %d which equals %d", a, b, sum);

  sum = addusinc (a, b);
  printf ("You added %d and %d which equals %d", a, b, sum);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Assembly file, saved with a .s format:

```
.global _addusina
_addus:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    subl    $16, %esp

    movl    8(%ebp), %eax
    addl    12(%ebp), %eax

    movl    %ebp, %esp
    popl    %ebp
    ret
```

Two additional things:

1. I don't have any issues with the external c function.
2. It does seem to recognize that the addusina getting used as in the main somewhere, because if I go back and change the name to not match the call, it then throws a 'declared but not used function' error.

So it looks like it is seeing it as a function on some level, because it recognizes that it is being used in the main.

Any pointers would be great, because I would like to get this fixed so I can actually start writing my own code.

Edit: I have removed the unneeded externs and fixed the movl typo and the name of the assembly function.

Edit 2: However, it is still throwing the same error, to a function name that does not exist any more, even after cleaning and rebuilding the project.

Comment: I'm confused: your C code makes no reference to `addus`, only to `addusina` and `addusinc`.  Is there something you are not showing us?

Comment: On what line exactly do you get the error? Is that `addus.c` what you showed?

Comment: Also, `move` should be `movl`.  Is this the actual code?

Comment: Remove the unnecessary `extern` please. But that said, this compiles fine with `gcc -Wall -c x.c x.o`, and I don't understand how you are getting object code to debug if you are getting a compiler error.

Comment: Thank you for all the replies. I have removed the unneeded extern. The professor was very specific in telling us to put them in for some reason. And yes, the error code is referring addusina. It was originally named just addus, and I changed it for clarity. I have also corrected the move instead of movl typo. I have cleaned and rebuilt the project but it is still saying "addus is not a function" even though I only have addusina and addusinc in the code.

Comment: I'm brand new to the eclipse environment, so I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, but I can not seem to get rid of errors to things that no longer exist. At first, I made all the changes suggested above, but the same error persisted. So I deleted all lines with any calls in them, cleaned and rebuilt the project, and I am still getting the same error to a call that now isn't even there any more. Any thoughts?

Comment: Suggest you just use `gcc` from the command line, or do whatever you need to do in Eclipse to do the equivalent of a `make clean`.

Comment: @abligh I'm pretty sure that's what I've done. I have cleaned (there are no .bin files, if that is what you are referring to) and have built the project, but it errors out on the line of code that's no longer there and does not generate a new binary. This is my first time using GCC, so I am not familiar with the command line prompts for it. Not really sure where to go from here, I think I may try a new project from scratch and copy the code in and see if the error goes away, since it seems like I can not truly clean it.

Comment: I compiled your program with `gcc` using `gcc -Wall -c x.c` just fine. I suspect eclipse. A new project sounds like the way forward.

Comment: I do as well. My experience with it has been short and unpleasant so far. I just tried a new project, typos fixed, eliminated the c function call and just tried to call the assembly code, without the extern, and am now getting "undefined reference to `addusina'"

Comment: Have you tried `.type _addus, @function` ?

Comment: Unlike other implementations of C, gnu C does not add the underscore to global/external symbol names. Have you tried it without the underscore (in the .s file)?